# How do I stop mod_rewrite from appending links to url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I expect the answer is going to be something so simple I'll want to cry, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm new to mod_rewrite.

I wanted to change my links from things like domain.com/?p=about to domain.com/about**/** (with the trailing slash) and it works fine, but whenever I move on to a link, it appends the new link to the back of the url.  For example, I have an about and a contact link.  If I click about it navigates to domain.com/about/ then if I click contact, it navigates to domain.com/about/contact/ and will keep adding the links to the end of the url.  If I'm at domain.com and click a link(about, in this case) it will go to domain.com/about/ and if I click about 4 more times, my address bar is going to say "domain.com/about/about/about/about/about/"  I have reproduced this in a very simple example below, what am I doing wrong?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

index.php

```
<a href="about/">about</a> | <a href="contact/">contact</a><br><br>

<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['p'])) {
        echo "home";
    } else {
        echo $_GET['p'];
    }
?>
```

Thank you for your help!

edit:
It works okay if I use an absolute path, but I'd rather not if I don't absolutely have to.

edit2: adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

breaks the links.  They appear to be going to domain.com/about/ and .../contact/, but I get a 404 - I'm assuming the rule I used is somehow incompatible with the way I'm doing my linking, which is why I included index.php as well.

Comment: How about adding a `RewriteBase /` just in between the other two lines in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: @Havelock: I've tried that too, but then the links no longer work at all.

Comment: then maybe have a look at how are you building the links on your pages... (whatever happened to tagging usernames o.O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining all of your links in HTML relative to the current path.

You will need to change your links such that:

```
<a href="about/">about</a> | <a href="contact/">contact</a><br><br>
```

becomes (note the leading / on the urls):

```
<a href="/about/">about</a> | <a href="/contact/">contact</a><br><br>
```

When you are on a page `site.com/about/us` a link like `<a href="home/"` gets resolved by the browser to be `site.com/about/us/home`.

The solution is to change all of your links, images, stylesheets, and javascripts to use absolute paths in your URLs, not relative ones like you have now.

EDIT:  Just noticed your edit.  You really should use absolute paths, not relative ones.  If you want to keep the relative URLs then you will have to use something like `<base href="/" />` on all of your pages.

Comment: Decided to use absolute paths (with a script that will set the path for me).  I was steering away from it so I wouldn't have to worry about it during development and production.  The server is different depending on where I am when I'm working on it that day, and I didn't want to have to change the path every time during the development.

Comment: If all the HTML is hardcoded then it can be an issue.  If you are using a web framework, they usually offer a mechanism for automatically determining the base path so all of your urls are portable.  If you're doing your own PHP site, you can define an application wide variable that holds the base URL of the site and then use that value when creating all of your links.

Comment: That's what I did drew, use a global variable based on which server it was running on (production, localhost, etc, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, clicking a `<a href="about/">about</a>` will append `about/` onto the end of the URL. That's how relative links work.

Your choices are, in order of sensibleness:

1. Just remove that trailing slash. That's the cause of your problem:

   ```
   <a href="about">about</a>
   ```

   A relative link will replace the last section of the path (after the last `/`) with your new value.
2. Add a preceding `../`. This is a bit hacky, but it lets you keep that valuable trailing slash

   ```
   <a href="../about/">about</a>
   ```
3. Do a 301 redirect from `/about/about` to `/about`. This will cause the address bar to change from `/about` to `/about/about` and back again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too late to answer, but adding this one line in the `<head>` section would do the trick:

```
<base href="/"> or <base href="your-domain-name">
```